# typeError for setting highchart dateFormats hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have created a singleton `highchart` element that use in my `react` + `typescript` app

```
import { lazy } from 'react';
import { messages } from '../../utils/baseComponent';
import moment from 'jalali-moment';

export let Highstock: {} | undefined;

Promise
  .all([
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "highcharts" */ 'highcharts'),
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "highstock" */ 'highcharts/highstock'),
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "highcharts-more" */ 'highcharts/highcharts-more'),
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "highcharts-solid-gauge" */ 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge'),
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "highcharts-exporting" */ 'highcharts/modules/exporting'),
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "highcharts-offline-exporting" */ 'highcharts/modules/offline-exporting'),
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "highcharts-export-data" */ 'highcharts/modules/export-data'),
  ])
  .then(imported => {
    const Highcharts = imported[0];
    const ImportedHighstock = imported[1];
    const HighchartsMore = imported[2].default;
    const solidGauge = imported[3].default;
    const exporting = imported[4].default;
    const offlineExporting = imported[5].default;
    const exportData = imported[6].default;

    Highstock = ImportedHighstock;

    HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
    solidGauge(Highcharts);
    exporting(Highcharts);
    exporting(ImportedHighstock);
    offlineExporting(Highcharts);
    offlineExporting(ImportedHighstock);
    exportData(Highcharts);
    exportData(ImportedHighstock);

    const dateFormats = {
      a: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('ddd');
      },
      A: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('dddd');
      },
      d: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('DD');
      },
      e: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('D');
      },
      b: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('MMM');
      },
      B: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('MMMM');
      },
      m: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('MM');
      },
      y: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('YY');
      },
      Y: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('YYYY');
      },
      W: function(ts: number) {
        return moment(ts).locale('fa').format('ww');
      },
    };

    Highcharts.dateFormats = dateFormats;

    Highcharts.setOptions({
      time: {
        useUTC: true,
        timezoneOffset: new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
      },
    });

    ImportedHighstock.setOptions({
      lang: {
        rangeSelectorZoom: messages.lib.view.remoteChart.timelineChart.zoom,
      },
      time: {
        useUTC: true,
        timezoneOffset: new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
      },
    });
  })
  .catch(e => {
    throw new Error(`Failed to load high charts. ${e}`);
  });

export const HighchartsReact =
  lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "highcharts-react-official" */ 'highcharts-react-official'));
```

This code worked fine on `react 16.7`, `typescript 3.7.5`, `highchart 7.1.2`, and `highchart-react-official 2.2.2`.

Recently, I updated some of my packages including `react` to `17.0.2`, `typescript` to `4.5.2` but did not change `highcharts'` packages.

Because of this update, I have an error that can't set value on `dateFormats` hook(as suggested by `highcharts` official document: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.html#.dateFormats)

[image]

I know that it's not possible to update imported objects, but this code was working fine before and I have error after updating my other packages but not `highcharts`. Is there a typescript way or `highcharts'` other option to bypass this problem?( I prefer to not updating `highcharts'` version since it may take some time and I prefer not to do that right now).

Appreciate any suggestions or workaround.

Comment: Hi @farzad, The problem is probably related to the way of importing the modules. As you can see in this simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-chaum-pi8ez?file=/src/App.tsx, you can add custom `dateFormats` declarations to Highcharts.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. You are right and the code snippet you sent works fine.  However the reason i'm using this approach for importing highcharts modules is  for lazy loading of them to prevent performance issue. This approach was working fine and these problesms occur after updating to mentioned libraries versions.

Comment: Could you try to load only `Highcharts` or only `Hightock`? In general `Hightock` contains `Highcharts`, so there can be some conflict due to importing them both.